# What is the "do-nothing" convolution kernel

Tags: image, image-processing, fft

If I am trying to do a convolution kernel in Frequency space - what is the "do-nothing" kernel. In other words, if I view the image after applying the kernel, and normalizing it in Frequency space, I just want to see the raw Fourier transform

Is it the identity matrix? my kernel is 3x3

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A do-nothing 3x3 kernel will be:

```
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 0
```

I hope I understood your question correctly - I'm not sure why you would want such a kernel, when it's much easier to just skip the convolution entirely.

Comment: I am trying to test some functions from the CUDA FFT libraries that do the matrix multiplication AND normalization all in one step. So assuming I ran the FFT of an image, using this kernel in your answer, my FT image should be the true image FT, as if no filter applied, right?

Comment: @Derek, right I think. I don't know what the convolution will do at the image boundaries so I can't say for sure.

Comment: There is no reason a kernel must be 3x3. You can lea e out all those 0’s, and make a 1x1 kernel.

Comment: @CrisLuengo that's true.  But the question specifically asked for a 3x3.

Answer (score 2):

The "do-nothing" convolution kernel is the Dirac delta function: "δ(x)".

The solution mark-ransom shared is just that! Any signal convolved with the Dirac delta is identical to the original signal. This applies to convolution in any n-dimension.

The Dirac delta has many other interesting properties:

- δ can be discrete or continuous in nature
- δ(0) = ∞
- The laplace transform of δ(x) equals 1
- The indefinite integral of δ(x) equals 1
- [see Wikipedia for more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Fourier_transform)

Also see [how to create δ convolutional neural network layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60782616/my-pytorch-conv1d-with-an-identity-kernel-does-not-produce-the-same-output-as-th/68061333#68061333)

Comment: Thanks! I updated the answer to be more relevant.