# My PyTorch Conv1d with an identity kernel does not produce the same output as the input

Tags: python, pytorch

I have:

```
        print('\ninp', inp.min(), inp.mean(), inp.max())
        print(inp)
        out = self.conv1(inp)
        print('\nout1', out.min(), out.mean(), out.max())
        print(out)
        quit()
```

My min, mean and max for my inp is: `inp tensor(9.0060e-05) tensor(0.1357) tensor(2.4454)`

For my output, I have: `out1 tensor(4.8751, grad_fn=<MinBackward1>) tensor(21.8416, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>) tensor(54.9332, grad_fn=<MaxBackward1>)`

My `self.conv1` is:

```
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv1d(
            in_channels=161,
            out_channels=161,
            kernel_size=11,
            stride=1,
            padding=5)
        self.conv1.weight.data = torch.zeros(self.conv1.weight.data.size())
        self.conv1.weight.data[:, :, 5] = 1.0
        self.conv1.bias.data = torch.zeros(self.conv1.bias.data.size())
```

So my weights look like: `tensor([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])`

So if I understand how convolution works, this should produce the same output. But it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

---

**It shouldn't.** You are probably forgetting the summation. As stated in the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Conv1d):

> In the simplest case, the output value of the layer with input size
>   (N, C_in, L) and output (N, C_out, L_out) can be precisely
>   described as:
>   [image: equation]
>
> where ⋆ is the valid cross-correlation operator, N is a batch size, C denotes a number of channels, L is a length of signal sequence.

Notice that, in your example, the mean after the conv (i.e., `21.8416`) is approx. 161 times the mean before (i.e., `161 * 0.1357`), and this is not a coincidence. Notice the same happening in the code below:

```py
import torch
torch.manual_seed(0)

# define the fake input data
x = torch.rand(1, 3, 5)
# >>> x
# tensor([[[0.4963, 0.7682, 0.0885, 0.1320, 0.3074],
#          [0.6341, 0.4901, 0.8964, 0.4556, 0.6323],
#          [0.3489, 0.4017, 0.0223, 0.1689, 0.2939]]])

# define the conv
conv1 = torch.nn.Conv1d(3, 3, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2)
conv1.weight.data = torch.zeros(conv1.weight.data.size())
conv1.weight.data[:, :, 2] = 1.0
conv1.bias.data = torch.zeros(conv1.bias.data.size())

# print mean before
print(x.mean())
# tensor(0.4091)

# print mean after
print(conv1(x).mean())
# tensor(1.2273, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
```

See? After the conv, the mean is 3 times the original one.

As @jodag said, if you want an identity, you can do like this:

```py
import torch
torch.manual_seed(0)

# define the fake input data
x = torch.rand(1, 3, 5)
# >>> x
# tensor([[[0.4963, 0.7682, 0.0885, 0.1320, 0.3074],
#          [0.6341, 0.4901, 0.8964, 0.4556, 0.6323],
#          [0.3489, 0.4017, 0.0223, 0.1689, 0.2939]]])

# define the conv
conv1 = torch.nn.Conv1d(3, 3, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2)
torch.nn.init.zeros_(conv1.weight)
torch.nn.init.zeros_(conv1.bias)
# set identity kernel
conv1.weight.data[:, :, 2] = torch.eye(3, 3)

# print mean before
print(x.mean())
# tensor(0.4091)

# print mean after
print(conv1(x).mean())
# tensor(0.4091, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
```

Comment: So there is no way for me to come up with an `identity kernel`?

Comment: @Shamoon You would need to have a single 1 for each output channel. For identity you would need to have all zeros except elements `for i in range(161): conv1.weight.data[i,i,5] = 1`

Comment: @Shamoon exactly. If you want to remove the for loop, you can simply do `conv1.weight.data[:, :, 5] = torch.eye(161, 161)`. I added an example for reference.

Comment: Thanks! It's getting me close, but not quite.

My inp mean is: `tensor(0.1003, device='cuda:0')`
Output is `tensor(0.1054, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)`

Comment: @Shamoon That is awkward. This op should be very stable numerically. If you could setup a Colab with a minimal reproducible example, I'd take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Convolution of a signal with a delta-dirac function always produces the original input. This applies to convolution of any n-dimension.

Note the delta-dirac is not the same as an "identity matrix", but it has similar behavior.

Here's an example with pytorch:

```
import torch as pt

num_chan_in = 3
num_chan_out = 3
image_size = 10
batch_size = 5
k = 3

# cnn with same number of input and output channels
cnn = pt.nn.Conv2d(num_chan_in, num_chan_out, kernel_size=k, padding=(k-1)//2)

assert num_chan_in == num_chan_out
with pt.no_grad():
    cnn.weight[:, :, :, :] = 0.0
    cnn.bias[:] = 0.0
    for i in range(num_chan_in):
        cnn.weight[i, i, 1, 1] = 1.0 # our equivalent delta-dirac

input = pt.randn([batch_size, num_chan_in, image_size, image_size])
output = cnn(input)

print((input == output).all())
```

prints "True".